# How to add MYSQL generated column with case

Tags: mysql, case, virtual

mysql version 5.7.25

This SQL returns 1064 error.

```sql
ALTER TABLE `contract` 
    ADD `newcolumn` INT 
    AS (CASE WHEN `price`=0 THEN `column1` ELSE `column2`) 
    STORED;
```

To simplify this error, I tried below SQL, but it returns 1064 .

```sql
ALTER TABLE `contract` 
    ADD `newcolumn` INT 
    AS (
     CASE WHEN (price=0) THEN 1 
       ELSE 2
    ) STORED
```

Comment: Post the table structure also `SHOW CREATE TABLE contract`

Comment: Your are missing the `END` clause try `ALTER TABLE contract ADD newcolumn INT AS (CASE WHEN (price=0) THEN 1 ELSE 2 END) STORED ;` if that does not work try `ALTER TABLE contract ADD newcolumn INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (CASE WHEN price=0 THEN column1 ELSE column2 END) STORED;`

Comment: END worked! Thank you.